# Magento 2 Customer Password and Email Settings

Tags: magento2, customer

Though this looks simple but I haven't been lucky to find the option to do the following in admin panel

1. I want the administrator to be able to set the customer's password manually
2. No emails should be sent to customer after they are created in backend

Answer (score 1):

1. This function was removed in Magento 2. There is only the option to reset a password for a customer.
2. You have to do change on code level.

Comment: how can change on code level

Answer (score -1):

1. login to magento 2 admin.
2. Go to system > All Users.
3. Select your User
4. reset password from 'User Info' > 'Account Information'

Comment: I had already tried that, it says customer will receive the email. It doesn't allow me to manually put a password.

Comment: More over the option you gave is to reset password for backend administrators (System users)